# Create a .cue sheet using metadata from multiple .flac files

Tags: metadata, tags, flac, cue-sheet, cue

I'm in the process of tidying up my Cayin N5 music library and the player itself seems to fail in reading metadata from .flac tracks of single album (it lists filenames instead of song names written in metadata).

So the question: is it possible to automatically generate a .cue file for all of these .flac files (which is a single album) using song names, album name etc. from a files metadata (tags)?

If so, how I can accomplish it?

P.S. *nix tools preferable as I don't have Windows

Thanks in advance!